# How to implement https->http gate in java

Tags: java, http, https, proxy

I need to implement HTTPS gate, which simply transmit requests to another fixed HTTP(no ssl) URL and return response in from it back to client. What is the simplest way of doing this? I try to use build-in com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer to receive request and java.net.HttpURLConnection to send requests. I think there will be some issues with transport headers(i must skip them?) and maybe some other. Maybe more elegant solution already exist?

Comment: take of a look of [my lib](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Intermediary.html)

Comment: I use com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer and transmit requests to another URL by HttpUrlConnection